Can't execute helper (external_acl_type) in Squid Proxy
Hello I am using Squid Proxy 3.5.23 and I want to limit user bandwidth using external_acl_type.
Inside my /etc/squid/squid.conf I configured:
auth_param basic program  /usr/lib/squid/basic_ldap_auth -v 3 -P -b "..." -D "..." -w "password" -f "..." -H "ldap://127.0.0.1" -Z

auth_param basic children 20 startup=5 idle=2
auth_param basic realm Squid Proxy
auth_param basic credentialsttl 3 hours
acl ldap-auth proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow ldap-auth

## end AUTH

external_acl_type perfil_acl %LOGIN /usr/lib/squid/perfil_ldap.py

acl perfil_laplace external perfil_acl

http_access deny perfil_laplace


First, I authenticate than I shouldn't access any web page, but I still can.
/usr/lib/squid/perfil_ldap.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    if not line:
        break  
    if line == "laplace":
        sys.stdout.write("OK\n")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write("ERR\n")

sys.stdout.flush()

But the python script never runs no matter how many times I authenticate.
How do I solve this?
EDIT 1:
My second attempt was using a shell script
#!/bin/bash

while read username; do
    if [ "$username" == "laplace" ]; then
        echo "$username" >> /usr/lib/squid/OK.log
        echo "OK"
    else
        echo "$username" >> /usr/lib/squid/ERR.log
        echo "ERR"
    fi
done


But ERR.log and OK.log haven't been created.
